# How to cover addeventlistener in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, addeventlistener, enzyme

Not able to cover below statements in jest.

```
initListener = (logout, refreshToken) => {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.addEventListener("onkeydown", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.addEventListener("onkeyup", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.addEventListener("onkeypress", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
};
```

and

```
logout = (logout, refreshToken) => {
  logout();
  redirect(appConstants.LOGIN, []);
  document.body.removeEventListener("click", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.removeEventListener("keyup", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  document.body.removeEventListener("keypress", () => this.reset(logout, refreshToken));
  storageClearAll();
};
```

Comment: Maybe you should read about events in React https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. What you're trying to do now is not *the React way* of doing that. Another helpful article is here https://frontarm.com/toolbox/react-events-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @lonut that it's not a react way of doing things.

Nevertheless if something like this need to be tested...

Before test:

```
document.body.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    });
```

In test its possible to check that listeners were added and imitate events like this

```
map.click(...)
map.keydown(...)
map.keyup(...)
map.keypress(...)
```